# Python - class using pop()

Tags: python, function, class

Ive got a problem with a stacking problem in python. In a class with 4 functions i need to use pop(). But It won't work the way i want it or I've got a problem with my list.

Can anyone help me with this.

```
class myStack(list):

    def __init__(self,a=[]):
        list.__init__(self,a)

    def push(self, x):
        self.append(x)

    def pop(self):
        return self.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self[-1]

    def emptyStack():
        if list.count != 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    c = myStack(list())
    c.push(3)
    c.push(5)
    c.push(7)
    print(c)
    print(c.peek())
    c.pop()
    print(c)
```

Comment: _"It won't work the way i want it or I've got a problem with my list."_ So, does it crash, or what? Please give more detail.

Comment: If you are inheriting from `list`, you don't even need to defined `pop()`, since your definition is identical to `list.pop()`. In the same spirit, you can define `push` simply as `push = list.append`.

Comment: Worth noting that the mutable default argument to `MyStack.__init__` could give you trouble down the line... Make it `__init__(self, a=None)` and make an empty list inside the method if necessary (`if a is None:`)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can call `list.pop` with passed `self` as first argument:

```
def pop(self):
    return list.pop(self)
```

or super:

```
def pop(self):
    return super(myStack, self).pop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You're sub-classing `list`, but `list` already provides some of the methods you're defining. If you don't want the full functionality of `list`, you're better off not using inheritance.

```
class MyStack(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._stack = list(args)

    def push(self, x):
        self._stack.append(x)

    def pop(self):
        return self._stack.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self._stack[-1] if not len(self._stack) else None

    def emptyStack():
        return not len(self._stack)
```

Answer (score -2):

This will call itself recursively:

```
def pop(self):
    return self.pop()
```

You probably mean

```
def pop(self):
    return list.pop(self)
```

Comment: If i use that i get the following result

[3, 5, 7]
7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python Workspace\ALDS\week2\week2_2.py", line 33, in <module>
    c.pop()
  File "D:\Python Workspace\ALDS\week2\week2_2.py", line 16, in pop
    return self.list.pop()
AttributeError: 'myStack' object has no attribute 'list'

Comment: `super(MyStack, self).pop()` would be the correct version of this. `self` has no `list` attribute in the implemention above

Comment: Or just `return list.pop(self)`, if you wanted to avoid `super` for whatever reason.

Comment: @chepner ok, changed my answer